# How to extract only SUDO version from Linux with python Subprocess

Tags: python, linux, bash, subprocess

I want to extract only the `SUDO` `version` from a `Linux` `output`. I have `command`

```
sudo -V 2>/dev/null| grep "Sudo version" 2>/dev/null
```

I want to do it with `Subprocess` I tried some ways but it's not working. As `Subprocess` takes a `list` of arguments but I am unable to use it correctly. How can we do it with Subprocess using `Python`?

Comment: Pass that exact command as a string (not list) and use the `shell=True` option.

Comment: The best solution is to run `sudo -V` only, and do the redirection and filtering in Python.

Comment: You could also just execute the command `["sudo", "-V"]`, and do the filtering in Python when you read the output.

Comment: If you want more detailed assistance, you need to post your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `subprocess.check_output`.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output("sudo --version", shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, encoding="utf-8").splitlines()[0]
'Sudo version 1.8.31'
```

- The flag `shell=True` is required to interpret the command line through your shell; otherwise you'd need to do `[shutil.which("sudo"), "--version"]`.
- `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` redirects sudo's stderr output to stdout, which is what `check_output` reads.
- `encoding="utf-8"` has `check_output` automatically decode the bytes output as UTF-8.
- `.splitlines()[0]` splits the output to lines and grabs the first one. If your `sudo` implementation doesn't print the version as the first line, you'd need to adapt that.